# django celery shows the error -- Process "ForkPoolWorker-1" pid:41 exited with "exitcode 70"

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a celery scheduled task in my django which runs at 4 PM. After the implementation of this scheduled task it worked smoothly and doesn’t shows any error. Yesterday my celery task was failed due to below error

```
Process "ForkPoolWorker-1" pid:41 
exited with "exitcode 70"
Task handler raised error: 
WorkerLostError('Worker exited 
prematurely: exitcode 70 Job: 1.')`
```

I don’t know why this error is coming. I am using

```
Django==3.2.4
celery==5.1.2
```

Some depreciation warning is also showing

```
version 6.0.0. Use the accept_content 
instead
The 'CELERY_TIMEZONE' setting is 
deprecated and scheduled for removal 
in   alternative=f'Use the 
{_TO_NEW_KEY[setting]} instead')
```

can any one help me to solve the above.My celery task is not a long running task.